# Cant Seem To use var twice in function

Tags: javascript, html

Okay heres my problem.. i am trying to make a button onclick in the function i have defined a variable but... i want to be able to click the button to a prompt type in a website in the prompt use window.location to go to which ever site... but when the user clicks ESC or cancel in a prompt its equal to (null or false). But when i click the cancel button it goes to null as if it was a href..

```js
function goToSite() {
  var done = prompt("Please Enter a Website You'd like to go to - Or click \"Cancel\" to go back to the main page.");
  window.location = done;
}
if (done === null) {
  window.location = "java_doc.htm";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goToSite()"></button>
```

Comment: Just a typo, right? A misplaced curly bracket

Answer (score 3):

You gotta make your conditional statement run before you change window.location, otherwise your address bar will point to null. Also, your function's closing brackets are in the wrong place, and you are closing your function before it actually does its thing.

```
function goToSite(){

    var done = prompt("Please Enter a Website You'd like to go to - Or click \"Cancel\" to go back to the main page.");

    if(done === null){
         window.location = "java_doc.htm";
    } else {
         window.location = done;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which could be `window.location = prompt('...') || 'java_doc.htm';`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG has a point, but `window.location = done || 'java_doc.htm'` might be easier to read with such a long prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
function goToSite() {
  var done = prompt("Please Enter a Website You'd like to go to - Or click \"Cancel\" to go back to the main page.");

  window.location = (done === null) ? "java_doc.htm" : done;
}
```

To take it one step further you can validate if the user actually entered a valid url.

```
function validUrl(textval) {
    var urlregex = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$/;
    return urlregex.test(textval);
}

function goToSite() {
  var done = prompt("Please Enter a Website You'd like to go to - Or click \"Cancel\" to go back to the main page.");

  window.location = (done === null || !validUrl(done)) ? "java_doc.htm" : done;
}
```

This makes sure that only if user entered a valid url, they will be taken to that url. Otherwise they will be redirected to your default page.